# flutter carousel image click to open new page

Tags: flutter, carousel

Example this Screen short, Click this Red Banner open new Page.
Any one please share Source code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AR1iS.jpg)

Comment: Please share what code you have tried so far. Stack over flow is not a code writing service. Look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's what you want but you can do it like this:

```dart
return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () async {
        await Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Page(), // The page you want
          ),
        );
      },
      child: Child(), // The banner
    );
```